# Debugging 14.04 freeze with syslog

Tags: drivers, kernel, debugging, syslog

Since upgrading to 14.04 a few weeks back, I have been experiencing a problem wherein Ubuntu will freeze (i.e. the entire UI stops working, can't drop down runlevels, etc.), and the only solution is to do a REISUB and software reboot.

I am fairly certain it has something to do with my graphics card (I am running an Intel Optimus, and it took some serious elbow grease to get it working on 12.04 as well), but to be honest when I inspect `/var/log/syslog` I have no idea what I am even looking for.

Is debugging with syslog the right approach?  If yes, what am I looking for?  If no, how would one go about debugging an issue like this?